# Can't use OR for AWK

Tags: linux, awk

I have a short script to search devices in a text file

Example db (inv.txt):

```
Rack:  RG01
Rack_units:  U11-U12
Serial:  10101NH
Name: Test01
Firmware:  v1.01

Rack:  RG05
Rack_units:  U12-U13
Serial:  10893NE
Name: Test02
Firmware:  v1.02

Rack:  RK11
Rack_units:  U14-U15
Serial:  10234JH
Name: Test03
Firmware:  v1.01

[...]
```

This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
/^Rack:/ {
  inStanza = 1;
  delete keep
  idx = 0
}
inStanza {
  keep[++idx] = $0
}
/^Serial:/ { if ($0 ~ find) { matched = 1; } else { matched = 0; } }
/^Firmware:/ && matched {
  for(i=1;i<=idx;i++) print keep[i]
  matched = 0;
  inStanza = 0
}
```

I'd like to search by `Serial:` and `Rack:`, for example:

```
 ➜ ./search.awk -v find=RG01 inv.txt
Rack:  RG01
Rack_units:  U11-U12
Serial:  10101NH
Name: Test01
Firmware:  v1.01
```

But right now it's working only for `Serial:`. I don't have any ideas how to do that. I tried to use `OR`, but it doesn't work for me

```
1. $1~/^(Serial:|Rack:)/ { if ($0 ~ find) { matched = 1; } else { matched = 0; } }
2. ($1 ~ /^Serial:/ || $1 ~ /^Rack:/) { if ($0 ~ find) { matched = 1; } else { matched = 0; } }
3. (/^Serial:/ || /^Rack:/) { if ($0 ~ find) { matched = 1; } else { matched = 0; } }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `$1 ~ /^(Serial:|Rack:)/` or better yet `$1 ~ /^(Serial|Rack):/` is the simplest solution, although `$1 ~ /^Serial:/ || $1 ~ /^Rack:/` would also work if you didn't backslash `$`.  It's not clear what you hope `serial_or_rack` would contain or what it should do.

Comment: Unfortunately, yours/my solutions doesn't work for me. `./search.awk -v find=RG01 inv.txt` lack of results, but for `./search.awk -v find=10101NH inv.txt` works, it's like only checking `Serial:` and omits `Rack:`. Anyway instead `serial_or_rack` should be `find` - I corrected it

Comment: Your original script doesn't work any better for me; https://ideone.com/pGP12x -- if I search for `10101NH` instead of `RG01` all three work (and my 4th cleaned-up version). Perhaps explain _in detail_ what you tried and how you hope the script should work.

Comment: Why it doesn't? I can see it prints only lines of device's information for serial number - 10101NH, and it's correct. But if you tried to type in the rack number (e.g. RG05 -> `find=RG05`), it wouldn't work

Comment: Exactly. So what should it do, under what circumstances, and what did you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your attempt is that it would zap the `matched` value if `Serial:` didn't match. So you want to refactor to only change `matched` if it wasn't already set for this record.

```sh
awk -v find="RG01" '
/^Rack:/ {
  inStanza = 1;
  delete keep
  idx = 0
}
inStanza {
  keep[++idx] = $0
}
/^(Rack|Serial):/ && !matched { matched = ($0 ~ find) }
/^Firmware:/ && matched {
  for(i=1;i<=idx;i++) print keep[i]
  matched = 0;
  inStanza = 0
}' inv.txt
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/RL9S7L

Comment: It works! That's exactly what I've been trying to do

Answer (score 1):

Your fileformat is perfectly designed for an easy awk manipulation. By defining the record separator `RS=""`, a single record is not the default line, but the entire block which you are interested in (empty lines separate the record separator). By defining the field separator to be a newline, we define the fields to be a single line in the record.

So the record `$0` would be:

```
Rack:  RG01
Rack_units:  U11-U12
Serial:  10101NH
Name: Test01
Firmware:  v1.01
```

and field `$2` would equal `Rack_units:  U11-U12`. Using `split` you can now split that in key-value pairs which makes it very practical to your problem:

```
awk -v find="STRING" '
     BEGIN{RS=""; FS=OFS="\n"; ORS="\n\n"}
     {for(i=1;i<=NF;++i) { split($i,a,":[ \t]*"); map[a[1]] = a[2] } }
     (map["Rack"] == find || map("Serial") == find)
    ' file
```